# Nexperia spice mosfet modell not working in LTspice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, spice, error

Hello I get errors with MOSFET spice models from Nexperia,

I've tried to include the spice fil within the asc and as .include to the lib, the error is the same.
I think it may be so that the spice syntax in the model is not correct for LTspice,
lambda seem to be a real variable for LTspice so on that one I don't understand why it complains.
[image]

[Link to: Mosfet in question](https://www.nexperia.com/products/mosfets/power-mosfets/PSMN017-80PS.html)

I get the following error

> Error on line 45 : .model m1:psmn017_80ps.lib nmos(vto=4.04250999509733 kp=1.5055e+02 nfs=0 eta=0  level=3 l=1e-4 w=1e-4 gamma=0 phi=0.6 lambda=0 is=1e-24  js=0 pb=0.8 pbsw=0.8 vmax=1000)
> * Unrecognized parameter "lambda" -- ignored
> Error on line 45 : .model m1:psmn017_80ps.lib nmos(vto=4.04250999509733 kp=1.5055e+02 nfs=0 eta=0  level=3 l=1e-4 w=1e-4 gamma=0 phi=0.6 lambda=0 is=1e-24  js=0 pb=0.8 pbsw=0.8 vmax=1000)
> * Unrecognized parameter "pbsw" -- ignored

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem looks to be due to this `.model` statement:

```
.MODEL MINT NMOS(Vto=4.04250999509733 Kp=1.5055e+02 Nfs=0 Eta=0
+ Level=3 L=1e-4 W=1e-4 Gamma=0 Phi=0.6 Lambda=0 Is=1e-24
+ Js=0 Pb=0.8 Pbsw=0.8 Vmax=1000)
```

There are a couple ways to fix it. The most straightforward is to delete `Lambda=0` and `Pbsw=0.8`.  It should look like this after you do that:

```
.MODEL MINT NMOS(Vto=4.04250999509733 Kp=1.5055e+02 Nfs=0 Eta=0
+ Level=3 L=1e-4 W=1e-4 Gamma=0 Phi=0.6 Is=1e-24
+ Js=0 Pb=0.8 Vmax=1000)
```

The justification for this is that `Lambda` is not supposed to be used with `Level=3` models, which is an error by whomever created the model.  `Pbsw` is the sidewall junction potential which LTspice doesn't use, which is fine because `Pb` (the bottom junction potential) is defined and at the same potential of `0.8`.